# How to do arithmetic with dataframe columns that contain spaces

Tags: r, arithmetic-expressions

I have a dataframe here and would like to create a new column that is the quotient of one column divided by another.

First, I tried:

```
df$new_column_name <- df$dividend column / df$divisor column
```

When I format it this way, I get the error:

> "Error: unexpected symbol in df$dividend column / df$divisor column"

I also have tried:

```
df$new_column_name <- df$"dividend column" / df$"divisor column"
```

Here I get the error:

> "non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Both columns being used for the math have spaces in the names if that makes a difference.

Comment: Please share your data.

Comment: if they are comments in colnames, then you must used backticks. Try typing `df$` in the console, then press <Tab> to see what I mean.

Comment: The general points being zeroed in on here are (1) don't use spaces in column names, and (2) to select column using a string, or if the name has something "bad" in it like spaces, `$` is a poor choice, instead do `df[["dividend column"]]`.

Comment: I think back-tics should do the trick. But please do share the data using `dput()` to give a detailed answer. `df$new_column_name <- df$\`dividend column\` / df$\`divisor column\``

Comment: Add an example of your data frame, `df`, otherwise you risk your question to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

As joran mentioned in the comments, it is really not advisable to have spaces in your column names. It can lead to lots of headaches. It does sound like your columns are not numeric. You can use `str` to look at the types of columns you have. An example is below with a possible solution to your problem using the tidyverse package, which I highly recommend checking out.

```
library(tidyverse)

# create data frame with space in column names
df <- data.frame("dividend column" = 1:5, "divisor column" = 6:10, check.names = FALSE)

# use str to get the classes of each column
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ dividend column: int  1 2 3 4 5
#>  $ divisor column : int  6 7 8 9 10

# use set_tidy_names to replace space in column names with '.'
# change columns to numeric values
# use dplyr::mutate to create the new column
df <- set_tidy_names(df, syntactic = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(c("dividend.column", "divisor.column")), as.numeric) %>% 
  mutate(new_column_name = dividend.column/divisor.column)
#> New names:
#> dividend column -> dividend.column
#> divisor column -> divisor.column
```